# To make it clear + question (or to be sure, to make sure)

Tags: phrases, questions

"To make it clear", "To be sure", "To make sure" + Question

I'm wondering if I can use some of them like this?:

```
To make clear, what is the most important requirement for the project?
To be sure, what is the most important requirement for the project? 
To make sure, what is the most important requirement for the project?
```

Is it correct to say those phrases when I want something to be more clear for me?

What is the difference between those phrases?

Comment: There probably isn't a huge difference, although "to make clear" sounds a bit awkward to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase is more often "To be clear".

Most likely you would not use this phrase in conjunction with an interrogative phrase.  Normally it is used with a declarative phrase which states your current understanding (even if you phrase the whole sentence as a question).

> To be clear, the thesis is the most important requirement for the project?

Comment: I would end that with ", right?" to ask for confirmation

Comment: And maybe start it with "Just".